# How do computers figure out date information?

Tags: datetime

Most languages have some sort of date function where you really don't have to do any programming to get any date information you just get it from the date function/object. I am curious what goes on behind the scenes to make this happen?

Comment: Could you be any more specific on what puzzles you here?

Comment: A lot... don't write your own :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every computer has a system clock which keeps track of date and time. On the lowest level, date and time information it retrieved from there. Above that add timezone information, etc. from the operating system and you got a Date object or something similar.

Depending on your language/environment Date objects can either perform date calculation themselves or you have to use other functions to achieve that. Those ensure that leap years get handled correctly and no invalid date can be created.

But maybe I got your question wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Typically a computer is storing a count of how many of a certain unit of time has gone by since a specific time and date in the past. In Unix systems, for example, this could be the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch, which is midnight, Jan 1st 1970 GMT. In Windows, this is the number of 100 ns intervals since 1601-01-0 (thanks **Johannes Rössel**). Or it could be something as simple as number of seconds since the computer was powered on.

So from the number of units that have gone by since that time/date, an OS can calculate the number of years, months, days, etc that have gone by. Of course all sorts of fun stuff like leap years and leap seconds have to be taken into account for this to occur.

Systems such as [NTP (Network Time Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_time_protocol) can be used to synchronize a computer's internal count to atomic clocks via an NTP server over a network. To do this, they NTP takes into account the round trip time and learns the sorts of errors the link to the NTP server.

Comment: Not all date/time systems are epoch-based, though. And not all epoch-based ones are second-based. Windows for example uses 100 ns intervals since 1601-01-01.

Comment: @Johannes Cool stuff, I didn't realise Windows had a different epoch to Unix- I thought they were both based on 1970.

Comment: Richard: Windows NT picked the beginning of the 400 year leap year cycle at its conception (1993) which happened to start in 1601. Also, since they used a 64 bit value from the start they didn't have to worry about a timespan only around a century long. Still, Windows is littered with different time formats, there are at least two more, one of which being SYSTEMTIME (a simple struct with several fields) and another being a human-readable string (dunno the name right now, though)

Answer (score 3):

Date and time information is provided usually by operating system, so it's a system call. Operating system deals with realtime clock mounted on computer mainboard and powered by small battery (which lasts for years).

Answer (score 3):

Well ... Most computers contain a "[real-time clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock)", which counts time on the human scale of seconds, minutes etc. Traditionally, there is a small battery on the motherboard, that lets the chip either remember the time, or even keep counting it, even when the rest of the computer is powered off.

Many computers today use services like the [network time protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to periodically query a centralized high-precision clock, to set the current time. In this way, even if the battery is removed (or just fails), the computer will still know what time and date it is, and be able to update (to correct for errors in the real-time chip's time-keeping) that information as often as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the realtime clock, date calculations are mostly a software library function.

Dates are rather irregular and so behind the scenes a mixture of approximations, corrections and lookup-tables are used.

The representation of a date can vary as well, usually some (arbitrary) startdate is used. A common system, also used by astronomers are the [Julian day numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Day_Numbers) (not to be confused with the [Julian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar)). Dates can be stored as seconds-since-start or as days-since-start (the latter is usually a floating point). Here are [some more algorithms](http://marauder.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/numbertheory/calendar/calendar.html).

Comment: The Julian calendar does not always get leap years correct.  Modern systems use the Gregorian calendar, which is nearly identical to Julian, but gets the leap years correct.

Comment: Not just modern systems - the Julian calendar has been replaced a few centuries ago. It's all in the linked page.

Answer (score 2):

A surprising amount of surprisingly complicated code is required for date parsing, computation, creation etc.

For example, in Java, dates are computed, modified, stored etc via the [Date](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and specifically and typically, the [Gregorian Calendar implementation of Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).   (You can [download the SDK/JDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp) and look at the source for yourself.)

In short, what I took from a quick perusal of the source is:  Date handling is non-trivial and not something you want to attempt on your own.  Find a good library if at all possible, else you will almost certainly be [reinventing the *square* wheel](http://www.districtadministration.com/viewarticle.aspx?articleid=931).

Answer (score 1):

Your computer has a system clock and the BIOS has a timer function that can be updated from your OS. Languages only take the information from there and some can update it too.

Answer (score 1):

Buy any of these books on [Calendrical Calculations](http://emr.cs.uiuc.edu/home/reingold/calendar-book/index.shtml).  They'll fill you in on how the date libraries work under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

The date/time is often stored in terms of times since a certain date.  For example ticks (100 nanosecond intervals) since January 1, 0001.  It is also usueally stored in reference to UTC.  The underlying methods in the OS, database, framework, application, etc. can then convert these to a more usable representation.  Back in the day, systems would store component parts of the date, day, month, year, etc as a part of the data structure, but we learned our lesson with the Y2K mess that this probably isn't the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Most replies have been to do with how the current date is obtained. i.e. from system clock and so on.

If you want to know how it is stored and used there are many different implementations and it depends on the system.

I believe a common one is the use of a 64 bit signed integer in T-sql the 01/01/1970 is 0 so negative numbers are pre 1970 and positive on from that each increment adding 100 th of a second (think it's a 100th would need to check).

Why 01/01/1970 you may ask this is because the gregorian calendar is on a 400 year cycle. 01/01/1970 being the closes start of a cycle to the current date.

This is because "Every year that is exactly divisible by four is a leap year, except for years that are exactly divisible by 100; the centurial years that are exactly divisible by 400 are still leap years. For example, the year 1900 is not a leap year; the year 2000 is a leap year." Makes it very complicated I believe the 400 year cycle coincides with the days of the week repeating as well but would nee dto check. Basically it's very complicated.

Internally it is incredibly difficult to write the datetime library accounting for all these variations such as leap years, the fact there is no year zero..... Not to mention UTC, GMT UT1 times.

Answer (score 1):

We had occasion when debugging a client problem to look at how SQL stores datetimes... fairly interesting and makes pretty good sense once you see it.

SQL uses 2 4 byte integers...
The first 4 bytes are the date in days since Jan. 1st, 1753.  I believe the maximum year is supposed to be 9999, which doesn't exactly line up to the number of available integers in 4 bytes, but there you go.
The second 4 bytes are the time in milliseconds since midnight.